# Why im getting this error 'Shake/Shake.h' file not found?

Tags: ios, flutter, shake

Hello while trying to archiving my app . Xcode giving me the following error .

```
'Shake/Shake.h' file not found
```

pubsec.yaml

```
  shake_flutter: ^15.1.0
```

When running my app on iOS device its works and giving no errors. But when trying to archive it it giving me the error . I tried ti delete pod file,flutter clean &flutter run ....
But nothing helped . So hope anyone can help.
App is written in flutter .

Comment: plz delete podfile.lock and Pods folder, run "pod cache clean --all" and then run.

Comment: Hey I did and know its working I deleted pods project, pod file,podfile.lock and pubsec.lock . And then flutter clean, then flutter pub get and finally cd iOS/pod install and flutter run.